# MenuItem bitmaps raises an assert failure …

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to have a nice bitmap of a gear in front of the `Preferences` menu item. This is how I think it should be coded:

```
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    preferences = wx.MenuItem(text="Preferences",
                              helpString="Opens preferences dialog.",
                              kind=wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
    gear = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'gear.png'))
    preferences.SetBitmap(gear)
    self.shcfg = fileMenu.Append(preferences)
```

However, this is wrong as I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "gui.py", line 193, in <module>                                          
    GUI(None)                                                                   
  File "gui.py", line 117, in __init__                                          
    self.InitUI()                                                               
  File "gui.py", line 129, in InitUI                                            
    preferences.SetBitmap(gear)                                                 
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at /tmp/pip-build-sc_vd1aj/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/src/gtk/menu.cpp(729) in SetBitmap(): only normal menu items can have bitmaps
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Append` rather than `AppendItem`

I suppose that there any number of ways to put a menu together but I have found that, all menu items require an Id.
For predefined `wx` id's it is straight forward as you can simply append them as they come not only with an in-built Id but also an image.
For custom images I use the method below, which has consistently worked for me.
Note that I have used both predefined Id's and custom Id's in this sample code.
I have included a variant of your code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
import os
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200, 100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # Create Statusbar
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        # Set up the menus
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        infomenu = wx.Menu()

        # file menu
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New") # Id of wx.ID_NEW (5002) which picks up an automatic image
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save")

        m1 = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, 100, "Manual Bitmap") #A manual id of 100
        m1.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('./myimage1.png'))
        filemenu.AppendItem(m1)

        m2 = wx.MenuItem(filemenu, 101, "Manual Bitmap 2") #A manual id of 101
        m2.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('./myimage2.png'))
        filemenu.AppendItem(m2)
        #----------------------------------------------#    
        preferences = wx.MenuItem()
        preferences.SetId(102)
        preferences.SetText("Preferences")
        preferences.SetHelp("Preferences Help")
        preferences.SetKind(wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        gear = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myimage2.png'))
        preferences.SetBitmap(gear)
        filemenu.AppendItem(preferences)
        #----------------------------------------------#    
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()

        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "Exit")

        # info menu
        infomenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About")

        # bind file menu
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnManualBitmap, id=100) # Bind to the Id
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnManualBitmap, id=101) # Bind to the Id
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnManualBitmap, id=102) # Bind to the Id
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        # Add menus
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&Preferences")
        menuBar.Append(infomenu, "&Help")

        # Add the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnManualBitmap(self, event):
        print event.EventObject.GetLabel(event.Id)
        print event.Id

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = MainWindow(None, "Menu Image Test")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Raises `AttributeError: 'MenuItem' object has no attribute 'SetId'`… I am running Python 3, not 2. Hacking the code so that it compiles raises the same error as in the question. ☹

Comment: You cannot run wxpython (classic) with python3. If you are running wxpython phoenix, as far as I know, it still isn't there yet! My answer runs happily using wxpython 3.0.2.0 gtk2 (classic) with Python 2.7.12 I guess it's all in the version ;)

Comment: I am running wxpython phoenix. So I guess I cannot do that. No worries.

Comment: You can bind to the menuitem name rather than the `id`, so in this case `preferences` but with wx classic the `id` in my testing came back with -2 for all items bound in this way, less than satisfactory. Phoenix may differ, although I still cannot find it documented and I would like to, as at some point, I am going to have to migrate a host of shareware projects to wx phoenix.

Comment: Phoenix is still in alpha/beta so I would not look too hard now. It is in a state of flux.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried omitting `kind=wx.ITEM_NORMAL`? It looks like it could be mishandled by wxPython and result in creating a checkable item instead. At least, this is what somehow ends up by happening, according to the assert message.